# can semigroup have two different one-sided identity?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a semigroup with binary operation '$*$'
and let's suppose there exist two left identity element $e,e' \in G$.

I want to show $e=e'$ but I need more assumption like existence of inverse, or commutative. 
so.... maybe $\{e,e'\}$ with binary operaion such that
$e*e =e$
$e'*e'=e'$
$e*e' = e'$
$e'*e = e$

can be a example of semigroup having two different left identity?

Is it possible to construct another example with $n(G)=m$ for all $m \in \mathbb N$ ?
How about $\mathbb N$? is it possible to define a binary operation having two different left identity? is same construction possible for $\mathbb R$?

($n(G)$ is the number of element of G)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:** Define binary operation as $x * y = y$; for all $x,y$ in some set. Is the set a semigroup? How many left identities are there?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that if you take any semigroup $G$ and adjoin the element $e$ such that $ea=a$ and $ae=e$ for all $a\in G$, then you still have a semigroup. In particular, if $G$ has a left identity, then $G\cup\{e\}$ has two left identities.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think assumption : 'there is no right identity' is critical. if there exist left, right identity $e_L, e_R$ then they are the same. So if there is right identity, there will be only one left identity, which is unique, two-sided. so another identity to insert must be left identity, not two-sided.

Comment: Yes, sorry I got confused - comment deleted!

Comment: Won't it lose the associative property? since $a(ea) = aa \neq (ae)a = ea = a$?