# Examples of 1-sided inverse/identity is not 2-sided inverse/identity.

Tags: abstract-algebra

This has been bothered for a long time.
So by the definition of the group,
for each $a \in G$, there is a $b \in G$ such that $ab = ba = 1$.(Similarly, for the 2-sided identity.)

Can anyone give me an example of group, where we can find
$a, b \in G$, such that $ab = 1$ and $ba \neq 1$?
and also an example of group where $G$ contains an element $1^* \in G$ such that $1^* a = a$ for all $a \in G$, but $b1^* \neq b$ for some $b \in G$?.

I know in certain case, 1-sided inverse and 2-sided inverse are equivalent in a nonabelian group, the simplest example I can think of is let $G$ be the set of  all bijective function for a finite set $A$, with the operation of function composition. In this case, the existence of 1-side inverse is sufficient for the 2-sided inverse. But in general, is there any condition that can make 1-sided inverse in a group be equivalent to the 2-sided inverse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing. If $ab=1$, then $ba=babb^{-1}=b1b^{-1}=bb^{-1}=1$.

Comment: WOW, does this means that the condition for 2-sided inverses is not necessary? so the definition of a group could be simplified into a set $G$ with a binary associative operation, and there exists a 2-sided identity,  and for each $a \in G$, there exists an element $b \in G$ such that $ab = 1$?  and b is automatically a 2 sided inverse?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Is there an analogy for the 1-sided identity? can we show that if there is a $1 \in G$ such that $1 a = a$ for all $a \in G$, then $b1 = b$ for all $b \in G$?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2077213/446262).

Comment: @DavidA.Craven I assumed that the other axioms hold.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven It seems to me that this answer is correct. So let me change some notation. Assume $G$ follows the usual definition of the group, except that for all $a \in G$, there exists a right inverse $a_R \in G$, such that $a a_R = 1$. Then $a_R a = a_R a a_R (a_R)_R = a_R (aa_R) (a_R)_R = a_R(1)(a_R)_R = a_R(a_R)_R = 1$, where $(a_R)_R$ is the right inverse of $a_R$, therefore $a_R$ is also the left inverse of $a$.  Is this argument correct?

Comment: @Andy I think I must have been tired. I have deleted my comments.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the definition of a group is that every element has a two-sided inverse, which is therefore both a left inverse and a right inverse.

It's very simple to show that an element can't have more than one left inverse: if $a$ and $b$ are both left inverses of $g$, then $1 = ag = bg$, so multiplying on the right by $g^{-1}$ gives $a=b$.

Similarly, an element can't have more than one right inverse.

So the two-sided inverse is the unique left inverse and the unique right inverse.

Answer (score 0):

So usually, a non commutative groupe G as the following proprieties :

Magma structure : There is an binary operation * on G, $*:G\times G\mapsto G$,

Associativitie : * is such that $\forall (a,b,c)\in G^3, a*(b*c)=(a*b)*c$,

Existence of neutral element : There exist an element e such that $\forall a \in G a*e=e*a=a$,

Inverse : There is a left and right inverse for all element $\forall a \in G,\exists (b,c)\in G^2 : a*b=c*a=e $.

*By looking at $c*a*b$, we can show that left and right inverse must coincide*

Usually, as you remark, we will use some argument of finitude (of the set, of dimension...) to show that the existence of left inverse implies the existence of right inverse.

The only idea that come to me of an associative magma with neutral element and left inverse is the fowllowing : Take the free magma indexed by the natural number (with 0), ie you take infinitly many letter $(x_n)_{n\in N}$ and consider all the world you can do with finitely many letter, with the concatenation of two word as a product. Note by e the empty word.

Then you will take the quotient by all the relation $\forall word1,word2,\forall n\in N,(word1*x_n*x_{n+1}*word2 = word1*word2)$ (ie you create the magma where $x_n*x_{n+1}=e$)

You can check that the resulting quotient with the natural law is a magma associative with e as neutral element, right inverse, but that $x_0$ as no left inverse

I have no idea about how to construct for the other question about a left neutral which is not right neutral